# How to retrieve content from Wikipedia for large lengthy queries?

Tags: javascript, api, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I tried retrieving data from Wikipedia API using

```
url: "http://en.wikipedia.org//w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=" + searchvalue + "&limit=12"
```

where `searchvalue` is the value gotten from a textbox. My problem is that I get desired results when `searchvalue = "the flash"` but I get no results(empty arrays) when `searchvalue = "the flash and the supergirl`. How do I make calls to the API to retrieve articles containing any of the words `searchvalue` if no articles exist that match that title exactly. I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=the+flash+and+the+supergirl&title=Special:Search&go=Go&searchToken=6wtdjlxknk7q715hkdp52cegf
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a boolean search:

> Boolean search – All major search engines support the "-" character for "logical not", the AND, the OR, and the grouping parentheses brackets: (_). Logical OR must be spelled in capital letters; the AND operator is assumed for all terms (separated by spaces), but capital AND is equivalent. Parentheses are a necessary feature because:  (blue OR red) AND green, differs from: blue OR (red AND green) -- [Wikipedia documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Advanced_search)

So if you wanted to search for "The Flash" *or* "Supergirl" `searchvalue` would be: `"the flash" or "supergirl"`.

[Here's that query in action](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&profile=default&search=%22the+flash%22+or+%22supergirl%22&fulltext=Search)

Comment: Thanks but I trying to send the data from Wikipedia to my app but I get empty arrays if there are more than two words in the query. So I thought of trying to retrieve contents which contain anyone of the words in the query. I don't understand how to do that through the boolean search like you answered above. Can you expantiate please?

Comment: You're getting an empty array because there were no matches for that search (it doesn't matter how many words are in the query). You don't need to search for all the words. Searching for "the" makes no sense. So you need to decide at some point how you're going to group your search, and that's usually done in the UI. I'm not sure how I can explain more than is already in the documentation, but I have updated that example link because it wasn't working, and that should explain what I mean,